# Tensorflow into an existing virtual environment

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, virtual, environment

I'm struggling to install tensorflow into an existing virtual environment on anaconda? I've done it once before but haven't been able to do it again.

I've tried:

```
conda activate base
conda install -c  anaconda pip
pip install tensorflow
```

I don't get any errors but I then have issues importing tf into Jupyter.

Comment: And what happened? What errors do you see? Please [edit] your post and paste in the text of these errors.

Comment: You should probably use anaconda to install tensorflow as it can also install the drivers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Dev-Keeks, Please follow this [TF Official](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) link to install tensorflow in your system. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

- mkdir tensorflow_files
- cd tensorflow_files

Now, you are inside the directory. Run the following command to create a virtual environment:

- python3 -m venv virtualenv

###### Activate the venv

- source virtualenv/bin/activate

###### Upgrade pip

- pip install --upgrade pip

###### Upgrade Tensorflow

- pip install -- upgrade TensorFlow